# Distinct top 25 SQL server query

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with creating a query with distinct and top. What i want is a top 25 with maximum values and a distinct by the parameter column.

My query now is:

```
select distinct top 25 
    startDate, parameter, min, max, avg, amount_called
from 
    VisualisatieData.dbo.metric_data_by_day_parameter
where 
    startDate between '2013-05-30 08:46' and '2013-05-31 16:00' 
    and endDate between '2013-05-30 08:46' and '2013-05-31 16:00' 
order by 
    max desc
```

This returns the following:

```
2013-05-31 01:08:26.000 P1  0   318386  1662    795
2013-05-31 00:01:36.000 P2  0   312325  1554    806
2013-05-31 00:01:36.000 P3  0   124827  25877   14
2013-05-30 08:49:19.000 P4  0   91992   11381   54
2013-05-31 01:05:54.000 P5  47  42410   497 499
2013-05-31 01:05:54.000 P6  16  42395   469 499
2013-05-31 01:05:55.000 P7  0   41380   244 498
2013-05-31 00:01:36.000 P8  328 35225   5305    8
2013-05-31 05:34:10.000 P4  16  12137   1208    17
2013-05-31 03:50:18.000 P9 0    11137   4687    23
2013-05-31 01:23:41.000 P10 391 8013    3237    95
2013-05-31 01:23:41.000 P11 375 7998    3174    98
2013-05-31 01:19:55.000 P12 453 7263    2437    58
2013-05-31 07:57:05.000 P13 2343    5639    3991    2
2013-05-31 03:32:21.000 P14 1687    5077    2993    9
2013-05-30 08:48:57.000 P15 984 5061    2419    12
2013-05-30 08:48:57.000 P16 984 5061    2419    12
2013-05-31 01:40:37.000 P15 1281    5045    2619    10
2013-05-31 01:40:37.000 P16 1281    5045    2619    10
2013-05-31 03:08:51.000 P17 562 4608    1302    18
2013-05-30 16:59:05.000 P18 4202    4202    4202    1
2013-05-30 16:59:05.000 P19 4202    4202    4202    1
2013-05-31 03:37:30.000 P20 875 4139    2681    18
2013-05-31 03:08:51.000 P21 547 3999    1203    18
2013-05-31 03:19:17.000 P22 31  3702    1399    5
```

This time there are 3 duplicate parameters what i dont want. Depending on the time selection there are more duplicates. I think this doesnt work because the distinct must be applied on only the parameter column.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 25 startDate, parameter, min, max, avg, amount_called
FROM
(   SELECT startDate, endDate, parameter, min, max, avg, amount_called, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by parameter order by max desc) subselect
    FROM VisualisatieData.dbo.metric_data_by_day_parameter
) A
where startDate between '2013-05-30 08:46' and '2013-05-31 16:00' and endDate between '2013-05-30 08:46' and '2013-05-31 16:00' 
ORDER BY max desc
```

But this doesnt work either, it returns the same as the first query.

I hope i described my problem clearly, if you want more information ask me.
How can i change my query so i get a top 25 with maximum values and no duplicate parameters? Suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, if P1, for example, appears more that once then only the P1 with the larger "max" value must be considered?

Comment: Yes thats true. Then the highest value of P1 must be shown.

Comment: Maybe just the other way round? Put the DISTINCT query as sub select and then take the TOP 25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to

```
select distinct top 25 
    startDate, parameter, min, max, avg, amount_called
from VisualisatieData.dbo.metric_data_by_day_parameter as tb
where 
    startDate between '2013-05-30 08:46' and '2013-05-31 16:00' 
    and endDate between '2013-05-30 08:46' and '2013-05-31 16:00' 
    and max = (select max(max) 
              from VisualisatieData.dbo.metric_data_by_day_parameter
              where startDate between '2013-05-30 08:46' and '2013-05-31 16:00' 
              and endDate between '2013-05-30 08:46' and '2013-05-31 16:00'
              and parameter = tb.parameter )
order by 
    max desc
```

then the same parameter will be removed

Comment: This gives me multiple errors. All the column names are invalid and incorrect syntax near where, expecting as, id or quoted_id

Comment: I forgot about endDate. Could you try now ?

Comment: Still the same errors. The columns from the first select are invalid. maybe the select ... from is not correct? and the syntax near where is still incorrect.

Comment: hmm I think that I also forgot about the alias for derived select
I added now an alias for `(select )`...last chance

Comment: now i got another error: Column 'VisualisatieData.dbo.metric_data_by_day_parameter.startDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: you can try now, I did my example on mysql and there worked. Now I provided small changes. but it'll work only if there is only one max value for parameter...if there can be two the same max values for paramter we can grou by all fields...I think so :)

Comment: Yep, but remember if they are two max values for example 25 and 25 for the same parameter it will return two the same rows...so then you can group it. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT startDate, parameter, min, max, avg, amount_called
FROM
(   SELECT startDate, endDate, parameter, min, max, avg, amount_called, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by parameter order by max desc) subselect
    FROM VisualisatieData.dbo.metric_data_by_day_parameter
) A
where startDate between '2013-05-30 08:46' and '2013-05-31 16:00' and endDate between '2013-05-30 08:46' and '2013-05-31 16:00' 
ORDER BY max desc
) as mytop LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: Sorry, my question wasnt clear. i am using SQL server so limit doesnt work.